# Cannot import ButtonBar class to javafx project

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, buttonbar

I just set up javafx and scenebuilder on intellij IDE and tried to follow [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/). Everything works except for ButtonBar class, for some reason I cannot import it to my fxml file.

When I do this:

`<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>`

it gives me an error `cannot resolve class` [`ButtonBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.html).

Any Idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Which `java` version have you installed? `ButtonBar` have been included since `Java8u40`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had installed jdk8u40, but I forgot to specify path to it in IntelliJ, that was the problem. Fixed it, works without problems now.